# Unable to add comments outside the editor in CK Editor 5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, angular12

Whenever i am trying add comments outside the editor in ck-editor 5.
Below error is coming:
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')**

Although i am following "ck editor comments outside the editor" document.

Link for "comment outside the editor for angular " :
(https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-collaboration-samples/blob/master/real-time-collaboration-comments-outside-of-editor-for-angular/src/app/editor/editor.component.ts)

But whenever i am clicking on add comment button, a comment pop-up is not opening and below error is coming.

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')**
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my scenario i have not initialise the side bar container and the side bar div container was inside the If condition, so in order to get rid of above mentioned error please initialise the side bar container during context setup and make sure your side bar div container should not be inside the If condition.